# jupyter notebook buffers when writing to file until closed? How to see results without closing jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new to python programming, had taught myself quickbasic back in high school and trying to  self teach myself python now using the only tools I have available right now - a chromebook running crouton with a jupyter notebook install on linux (which may be my first set of mistakes, teaching myself and learning using an "interesting" set up, but here I am). Anyhow, I am regularly finding interesting links on the web on my phone and emailing myself them to review later, and I figured I would create a python program to sort the list of URLs and output them to file.

I included the code below, which does work, but the problem I have is with jupyter notebook itself, and I googled a bit to try to find an answer but was unsuccessful so far. Here is the actual issue:

When I write to file in jupyter notebook, it does not show up in local filesystem until I close out the jupyter notebook. This is less than ideal, as I like to use the jupyter notebook for quick testing and bug fixing instead of using idle or bash, so having to close out of jupyter notebook just to see what is output to file is not helpful. Is there a way to flush buffer or something so as to be able to open the text file in a text editor and see the results - without having to quit out of the jupyter notebook?

-if needed, here is the program:

```
##################################################################
#                                                                #
# parse_my_search.py - I save URLs to a text file for later      #
# viewing and/or bookmarking. These lists grow rather quickly,   #
# so this is a program to sort them by certain subject or        #
# websites and make sure that I have no duplicates.              #
#                                                                #
##################################################################


import os.path
from os import listdir


URL_set = {}   # set - used to remove duplicates when sorting/organizing
URL_list = []  # list - used to allow duplicates when sorting/organizing

temp_list = [] # list - temporary usage, discard or reassign to [] when not used

input_file = ""   # file to read in, get the URLs, and then close  

output_file = 'python.txt'  
                  # file name for output. Will probably change this to a list to write the 
                  # output files to. This should NOT overwrite
                  # the existing file, but it should open a python file (as in, a text 
                  # file with extention '.txt' which has the URLs that include the word
                  # 'python' in it), a youtube file (any/all youtube URLs), and an 'else' 
                  # file that is the catch-all for anything that is not in the first two
                  # files. NOTE: this has not been done yet, only opens single file


input_file = 'My_searches.txt'

while True:
    try:
        #for elem in os.listdir('.'):
        #    print(elem)

        #print(os.listdir('.'), end=" ")
        #print(onlyfiles)
        #print("enter filename")     
        #input_file = input()
        read_from = open(input_file)
        break
    except OSError as err:
            print("OS error: {0}".format(err))


ItemsReadInFromFile = read_from.readlines()

for item in ItemsReadInFromFile:
    URL_list.append(item.strip('\n'))

# using list comprehension to 
# perform removal of empty strings
URL_list = [i for i in URL_list if i] 

# removing duplicates:
URL_set = set(URL_list)
URL_list = list(URL_set)

URL_list.sort() # this will change the list/ is destructive. No need to do the following:
                #     URL_list = URL_list.sort()
                # In fact, doing so returns 'None'

# sorting for python        
write_to = open(output_file, 'w+')
for item in URL_list:
    if 'python' in item.lower():
        item += ('\n')
        write_to.write(item)



# this is a test that the program works to this point                    
print("so far so good", input_file)
read_from.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer today, and it turns out that it was not jupyter at all but instead was due to after writing the data not closing the file at the end of the program. This is why jupyter did not have the data written to file and showing in a text editor (until jupyter was closed), the file was still open.

Insert facepalm here.

A rookie mistake, and a little embarassing, however I am happy that I figured it out. This can now be closed